# Extract some modeled values from glmmTMB object

Tags: r, mixed-model, regression-coefficients, glmm, glmmtmb

I modelled some dummy data in `glmmTMB` package in R:

```
set.seed(1234)
area <- sample(1:1000, size = 55)
mydata <- data.frame("species" = c("A1", "A1", "A1",
                                   rep(c(paste0(LETTERS[1:26], 1:26), 
                                       paste0(1:26, LETTERS[1:26])))),
                     "area" = area,
                     "tot" = sample(1000:1500, 55),
                     "humans" = rnorm(55),
                     "land" = rnorm(55),
                     "roads" = rnorm(55))
head(mydata)
  species area  tot       humans       land      roads
1      A1  284 1357  0.831521512 -0.0139409 -0.2261837
2      A1  848 1183  1.378491660  0.1686369 -0.6063149
3      A1  918 1306  1.574904176  0.8692633  2.0200296
4      A1  101 1389 -0.572594806 -0.7986699 -0.4946306
5      B2  623 1304  0.008159591 -0.5037505  0.4332016
6      C3  905 1220 -0.472049254  2.3155983 -1.6955075
```

Some species can have more than one values (in this case, species `A1`). I am interested in seeing what is the relationship between my response variable `area` and my independent variable (or covariate) `roads`. I suppose there is a difference in how each species behaves and how each species will specifically respond to `land`, and therefore I will include a random intercept for `species` and also a random slope for `land`. I decided to use a negative binomial distribution with offset (log of `tot`) instead of a beta distribution. Therefore, my model formula looks like:

```
mymod <- glmmTMB(area ~ humans + land + roads  + 
                    offset(log(tot)) + (land | species),
                    data = mydata,
                    family = nbinom2)
```

Right now I am not interested in the model itself, but rather in plotting the modelled values for each species, because I think some of them may be of interest to me. I think I found out how to do it for the random effect (`land`):

```
mod_eff <- subset(as.data.frame(glmmTMB::ranef(mymod)), 
                  term == "land")

ggplot(mod_eff,
             aes(x = condval, y = grp)) +
  geom_point(size = 7, aes(color = factor(grp))) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linewidth = 1, color = "grey50")
```

[image]

Now I would like to do the same for one of the fixed effects, namely `roads`. As it is *fixed* (and therefore, if I understood correctly, it's not supposed to vary across species), if I compute the coefficient for `roads`, it is the same across all species.

```
mod_eff <- glmmTMB::fixef(mymod)$cond[4]
mod_eff
     roads 
0.01550543
```

However, even if the effect is fixed, the modelled values should be different among species because the response variable has different values, right? (I am not 100% sure if I am understanding this correctly). At this point, I think I can compute by myself the modelled values by using this coefficient, but I am not sure how (if by multiplication, by exponentiation...). I'm not even sure what I want to achieve has sense or is actually doable.
I want to extract these values from the whole model and not by modeling the species separately because I think if I model them separately, the values will be different than if I model them all together with the others.